# Installing fpc package in R incomplete

Tags: r

I am going to install fpc package in R. The command I tried to intall it is:

```
install.packages("fpc", dependencies = TRUE)
```

and I got this message:

```
The downloaded packages are in /tmp/RTmpuM8LCb/download_packages
```

But when I try to use it by `library("fpc")` I got this error:

```
Erro in library("fpc"): there is no package called 'fpc'
```

It seems it is not installed correctly but I do not understand where is the problem? Any one have any idea to help me?